# Making a common function for getting value in JS

Tags: javascript, function

I have a few functions like these:

```
getA1: function (customUniqueValue) {
  return this.tempRows[customUniqueValue].A1
}

getA2: function (customUniqueValue) {
      return this.tempRows[customUniqueValue].A2
    }

getA3: function (customUniqueValue) {
      return this.tempRows[customUniqueValue].A3
    }
```

I call each of these functions from my HTML code by passing the corresponding value. As you can see, all of them can be merged into a single function if I can somehow pass the key to the function which can be used for fetching. For example, I did this:

```
getValues: function(customUniqueValue, keyToBeFetched) {
      return this.tempRows[customUniqueValue].keyToBeFetched
}
```

And I am calling the above function as,

```
   getValues(customValue, 'A')
   getValues(customValue, 'B')
   ..........
```

The only issue is, this somehow doesn't work. The `getValues` function doesn't seem to recognise `keyToBeFetched`. Do I have to pass this key differently? Or convert it to a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change it to brackets notation:

```
getValues: function(customUniqueValue, keyToBeFetched) {
      return this.tempRows[customUniqueValue][keyToBeFetched]
}
```